# Using foreign Key in DbInitialize class. Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I have two entities

```
public class Datatype
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(96)]
    public string DataTypeName { get; set; }        
}

public class Attribute
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(96)]
    public string Attribute_Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Datatype")]
    public int? DatatypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Datatype Datatype { get; set; }
}
```

In DataBase Initialize I have this code

```
    Datatype dt = new Datatype();
    dt.DataTypeName = "text";
    context.datatypes.Add(dt);
//Above code is working fine. And After execution I can see
//in records a row.. with id=1 and datatype=text
    Attribute at = new Attribute();
    at.Attribute_Name = "Description";
    //at.DatatypeId = 1;                   But if I uncomment this line
    context.attributes.Add(at);           // Then This Gives Following Error
```

---

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
"FK_dbo.Attributes_dbo.Datatypes_DatatypeId". The conflict occurred in database
"dyescan", table "dbo.Datatypes", column 'Id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the above code executes before either of the two objects have been saved to the database then it will not work simply because your object 'dt' will not have an ID of 1 before it's been saved to the database and therefore you cannot associate with attribute on '1' YET!

Instead you should not set the 'DatatypeId' but simply set the 'Datatype' like so:

```
at.Datatype = dt;
```

This will leave entity framework to figure out what the actual foreign key associated should/would be when savechanges is called.

Comment: Though the problem is something else as well because, in generate DB I can see that all other tables are named exactly as I wrote in mycontext class. e.g. `items,attributes` except `datatypes` it is generated with name `data_type`, but it should be `datat_types` according to `mycontext` yet Thanks that your solution is working anyway.